# get data from two array with jquery from php json encode

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am newbie in this thing, i have searched on internet but not work for me, maybe someone can give me solution to get data from two array from json encode

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

$viewEO;
$viewAcara;

$ideve=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$mysql = ("SELECT id_eo,nama as namaEO,logo,deskripsi as DeskEO,email,telp from eventorg WHERE id_eo='$ideve'");
$result=mysql_query($mysql);
if (!empty($result))
{       
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $viewEO[] = array(
     'idEO' => $row['id_eo'],
     'namaeo' => $row['namaEO'],
     'deskripsieo' => $row['DeskEO'],
     'email' => $row['email'],
     'telpon' => $row['telp'],
     'logoeo' => $row['Logo']
     );
  }
}

$mysql2 = ("SELECT id_acara,nama,tanggal,endtanggal,lokasi,imagePath,deskripsi,id_eo from acara WHERE id_eo='$ideve'");
$result2=mysql_query($mysql2);
if (!empty($result2))
{       
  while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
    $viewAcara[] = array(
    'idacara' => $row2['id_acara'],
    'namaacara' => $row2['nama'],
    'deskripsi' => $row2['deskripsi'],
    'tanggal' => $row2['tanggal']
    );
  }
}

mysql_close($con);

$final = array('array1'=>$viewEO, 'array2'=>$viewAcara);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);
?>
```

and this is my html code

```
var arrEOS=new Array();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'phpmobile/viewdetaileo.php',
            data: { "id": tempideo},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                    if (arrEOS.indexOf(item.ideo)<0)
                    {   
                        $('#daftaracara').append('<li data-role="list-divider" >'+item.tanggal+'</li><li><a onclick="detailAcara('+item.idacara+')"><h2>'+item.nama+'</h2><p><strong>'+item.deskripsi+'</strong></p><p>'+item.lokasi+'</p></a></li>');  
                        arrEOS.push(item.idacara);      
                    }
                    $('ul').listview('refresh');


                    $("#img1").html('<img id="img1" src="web/'+item.logoeo+'">');
                    $("#namaeo").html(item.namaeo);
                    $("#deskEO").html(item.deskripsieo);
                    $("#telpon").html(item.telpeo);
                    $("#email").html(item.emaileo); 

                });

            },
            error: function(){
                //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

Thank you before, Have a nice day :)

Comment: On ajax success you can get the json responce as item.array1['ideo'];

Comment: hey @KarthikN thank you for your fast response, are u mean like this "success : function(responce)" i am really new in json things

Comment: sorry I can't get you @Rei. instead of item.ideo try to check the value as item.array1['ideo']

Comment: @KarthikN like this? $("#img1").html('<img id="img1" src="web/'+item.array1['logoeo']+'">');
      $("#namaeo").html(item.array1['namaeo']);
      $("#deskEO").html(item.array1['deskripsieo']);
      $("#telpon").html(item.array1['telpon']);
      $("#email").html(item.array1['email']);

Answer (score 0):

The json data you send from the php is `$final = array('array1'=>$viewEO, 'array2'=>$viewAcara);` your looping is wrong.

This can be done in many idea what I am suggesting is, try to use two new loops with in ajax success

```
$.each(data.array1, function(i,item){ 

//do the operations you want to perform with these vaules
    console.log(item.idacara);
    console.log(item.namaacara);
    console.log(item.deskripsi);
    console.log(item.tanggal);
}
```

and

```
$.each(data.array2, function(i,item){ 
//do the operations you want to perform with these vaules
    console.log(item.logoeo);
    console.log(item.idEO);
    console.log(item.namaeo);
    console.log(item.deskripsieo);
    console.log(item.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you only have two array exactly,

```
 $.each(data, function(i,item){
                if(i == "array1"){
                //for array1
                    console.log(item[0].idEo);
                }
                else{
                //for array2
                    console.log(item[0].idacara)
                }
```